# starting reachable analyzer with domain?

Tags: amazon-vpc, amazon-reachable-analyzer

Is it possible to use the reachable analyzer with a domain?

I really want to start at a domain. For example, i would take a domain `www.example.com` and run the reachable analyzer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VPC Reachability Analyzer does not yet support setting a domain as a destination.

However, if you can resolve the domain into a destination IP address, it is possible to configure the **destination type** of the analysis to be an `IP Address`.

Setting the destination equal to an `IP Address`, the analysis traces the path followed by the network packet according to the actual routing rules of your network, as if it was really emitted by the source. This can help you identify whether

- the packet is eventually dropped by the network, or
- the packet reaches a terminal network resource, or
- the packet eventually leads out of your network (into a different region or into a different account if you don't have cross-account support enabled), or
- the packet reaches a network resource that is not yet supported by VPC Reachability Analyzer

In the last case, the network path normally stops at some **VPC Route Table** with an `UNSUPPORTED_COMPONENT` explanation.